# code works in spyder (python 3,7) but not in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

## The following code works in spyder

```
import re

price_num = []
for row in df['price']:
    price_no_nonnum = re.sub('[^0-9]','', row) # this code line works in spyder
    price_num.append(int(price_no_nonnum))
```

## In Jupyter notebook, I am getting an error

```
import re

price_num = []
for row in df['price']:
    price_no_nonnum = re.sub('[^0-9]','', row) # this code line gives an error in  jupyter
    price_num.append(int(price_no_nonnum))
```

Following error comes in Jupyter

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b3f4fcbe9d89> in <module>()
      3 price_num = []
      4 for row in autos['price']:
----> 5    price_no_nonnum = re.sub("[^0-9]","", row)
      6    price_num.append(int(price_no_nonnum))
      7 

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    177     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    178     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 179     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    180 
    181 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Jupyter is using python3.4 but as you point out spyder is using python3.7 so it is probably an incompatibility of python versions (some change of the re module)

Comment: Hmm are you certain the contents of the dataframes are identical?

Comment: Yes, the dataframes are identical. Can someone provide what code change I should make in Jupyter

Comment: My goal is to remove non-numeric characters from the 'price' column of 'df' dataframe and then change the dtype to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `row` is not a string, but some Pandas-specific datatype. You could try this and avoid using the regex altogether:

```py
price_num = []
for row in df['price']:
    try:
        price = int(row)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        price_no_nonnum = ''.join(c for c in str(row) if c.isdigit())
        price = int(price_no_nonnum)
    price_num.append(price)
```

Comment: I tried the code, but got the following error:TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: 'price' is a non-null object

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like. Is it all strings that you want the digits of? Is it some ints and some strings and some floats? Are there any things that you don't want to add to the list?

Comment: The column values have numeric and non-numeric characters along with a ',' For example  $8,500

Comment: Is there a way I can attach the .csv file here, so that may help you look at the data. Your hep is much appreciated as I learn this new field.

Comment: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call when I tried str(row)

Comment: I edited my original post to try and accept an int, otherwise to parse an int from the string.

Comment: It worked! For my better understanding, what does ValueError do?

Comment: If you run the command `x = int("foo")`, Python will raise a `ValueError` because the value of the string was not a valid value to convert to an int. It's always better to catch specific errors than it is to do a bare `try: ... except: ...` because you risk silencing errors you don't mean to.